# R - Successfully changing class to Date, later recieving Warning: class discarded from column

Tags: r, class, date, character

I'm successfully changing a vector of dates with a character class to a date class, but later I receive the warning message: "Warning: class discarded from column." At that point, any sorting I may have done is undone and the class has switched back to being character. This typically occurs after I have run the fix() function. Can someone explain what is going on here and how I can resolve this issue? My code is below, thanks in advance for any insight!

```
    > class(gt$game.date)
    [1] "character"
    > gt$game.date <- as.Date(doc.date[gameday.position], "%m/%d/%Y")
    > gt.sorted <- gt[rev(order(as.Date(gt$game.date))),]
    > class(gt$game.date)
    [1] "Date"
    > fix(gt)
    Warning: class discarded from column ‘game.date’
    > class(gt$game.date)
    [1] "character"
```

Comment: Don't use `fix` when dealing with Date or other classes - it is a primitive data editor that doesn't cope well. Try `View` instead if you just want to take a gander at something.

Comment: fix (and edit) work only with data frames having certain simple sata types. From the edit.data.frame doc -- `At present, this only works on simple data frames containing numeric, logical or character vectors and factors, and numeric, logical or character matrices. Any other mode of matrix will give an error, and a warning is given when the matrix has a class (which will be discarded).`